# Why can't I add save more than 1 object in my LinkedList while using JDO?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, linked-list

I am using google app engine and JDO. In one of my servlets i am adding objects in a linkedlist and saving everything using persistence manager. Till the end of servlet it shows that everything is working fine. it appends the linkedlist ok. But when i try to fetch that linkedlist from datastore by using jsp page, i figure out that only one object is added to that linkedlist. Rest of the objects which i added in linkedlist are not saved in datastore. Why is it happening?
Thanks in advance.
here is the code:

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
    throws IOException {

  resp.setContentType("text/html");

  PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
  try
  {
//.... 
    for(int j=0; j<coordinate.length; j++){
        if(j < locations.size()){
                locations.get(j).getCoordinate().setLatitude(coordinate[j].x);
                locations.get(j).getCoordinate().setLongitude(coordinate[j].y);                         
        }else{
                        loc.setLatitude(coordinate[j].x);
                        loc.setLongitude(coordinate[j].y);
                        locat.setCoordinate(loc);
                        locations.add(locat);
        }
                   System.out.println(locations.size());
    }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error fetching runs: " + ex);
    }final{
        pm.close();
    }
 }
```

Comment: You probably have a bug in your code. I would look at line 142.

Comment: I am watching values by using println statement. and when i am at the end of my servlet, size of linkedlist is what i want. but when i access it from datastore then that problem occurs.

Comment: Sure. If you want us to help with your code, show your code. We don't have a crystal ball.

Comment: i edited my question with code. please have a look.

Comment: Where is locations defined? Where does it come from? Where is locat defined? Are you sure you don't add the same locat object to the lists several times, which would explain that the datastore stores it only once?

Comment: I am new with JDO so didn't know that. Now its working fine when i defined locat in loop. Thank you so much for your help. I dont know how to accept your comment as an answer. Please answer it and then i will accept it as a accepted answer. Thanks again.

Comment: It has nothing to do with JDO, but all to do with Java. See my answer for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not complete, so it's hard to be sure, but I suspect that you're basically doing this:

```
Location locat = new Location();
List<Location> locations = ...;
for (int j = 0; j < coordinate.length; j++) {
    // ...
    locat.setCoordinate(loc);
    locations.add(locat);
}
```

In Java, adding an object to a list doesn't make a copy from the object into the list. The list simply stores a reference to your object. So, at each iteration, you overwrite what you stored in the object at the previous iteration, and add a new reference to the same object in the list. At the end, the list contains N references to the exact same object.

So when the datastore stores the list in database, it notices that the list contains the same object duplicated n times, and only stored the object once.

You thus have to make a new location object at each iteration:

```
List<Location> locations = ...;
for (int j = 0; j < coordinate.length; j++) {
    // ...
    Location locat = new Location();
    locat.setCoordinate(loc);
    locations.add(locat);
}
```